# Laravel Echo + Laravel Passport auth in private / presence websockets channels

Tags: laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I'm trying to connect to a **presence wesocket channel** using Laravel Echo. I'm also using Laravel Passport. I followed lots of tutorials, but I'm getting 403 error codes, 302 codes and so on. I'm hosting my websocket server locally, using [laravel-websockets](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) library to handle connections. Vue is my front-end library.

This is what I tried:

- Edit the **BroadcastServiceProvider**'s boot function.

  ```
  public function boot() {
              Broadcast::routes(["prefix" => "api", "middleware" => "auth:api"]);
              require base_path('routes/channels.php');
          }
  ```
- Add the **Authorization token** to Echo headers and add an `authEndpoint` property in *bootstrap.js*

  ```
  window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'pusher',
   authEndpoint: '/broadcasting/auth',
   key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
   auth:{
       headers:{
           'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token,
       }
   },
   cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
   //encrypted: false
   wsHost: window.location.hostname,
   wsPort: 6001});
  ```
- Try **joining the channel** from Vue.

  ```
  mounted(){
  Echo.join(`game.0`)
      .here((users) => {
          alert("In the channel!");
      })
      .joining((user) => {
          console.log("Someone entered");
      })
      .leaving((user) => {
          console.log(user.name);
      })
      .listen('GameEvent', (e) => {
          console.log("Hey")
      });}
  ```
- **routes/channels.php** file:

  ```
  Route::prefix('/user')->group(function(){
  Route::post('/login','api\v1\LoginController@Login');
  Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/all','api\v1\user\UserController@index');});
  ```
- The **event file**:

```
class GameEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $gameEvent;
    public $gameId;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($gameEvent,$gameId)
    {
        //
        $this->gameEvent = $gameEvent;
        $this->gameId = $gameId;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        //return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
        return new PresenceChannel('game.0');
    }

    public function broadcastWith(){
        return $this->gameEvent;
    }
}
```

At this point, if I try to connect to the channel, the *broadcasting/auth* request gets a 302 code (Found). I found an answer in another post that claimed to solve this by adding this to the **routes/web.php** file.

```
Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', function(Request $request){
$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher(
    env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
    env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
    array(
        'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        'useTLS' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => 6001,
        'scheme' => 'http',
    )
);
```

**IT WORKED**, *the broadcasting/auth* request gives a 200 code, and I get this as a response:
`{"auth":"ABCFEDG:0bfff7db6506158755b012a47873799849d4e6b331f68da4bedd1caea04ad657"}`

but the `here, joining, leaving` functions are not triggering.

```
Echo.join('game.0')
    .here((users) => {
        alert("In the channel!");
    })
```

What should I do to get this to work?

Screenshot of the network inspector:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you add auth route in channel.php ?
please check it
You should make it based on channel name

```php
Route::channel('game.'.$id,function($user,$id){
return .....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

no channels there .  Did you miss Broadcast::channel  ?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your authEndpoint like this

```
authEndpoint: window.location.hostname+'/api/broadcasting/auth',
```

and don't forget to update your BroadcastServiceProvider

```
    Broadcast::routes([
    'prefix' => 'api',
    'middleware' => 'auth:api'
]);

require base_path('routes/channels.php');
```